# VS 2013 not responding

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I've been using a solution which contains three projects for a long time.  Something has changed, and now VS is hanging when trying to open one of the projects in Solution Explorer.  The three projects consist of a Fortran dll project, a C dll project, and a CPP mfc executable project.

I can build successfully, and can view the Fortran and CPP files in solution explorer.  However, when I try to open the C project in explorer, VS hangs.

I created a new solution and re-created the C dll project in that solution, by adding the C source code files.  It worked fine when using solution explorer to view the source code.

Then I replaced the C dll project in the original solution with the new C dll project.  However, VS still hangs when I try to view the files in the C dll project.

I then replaced the C dll project in the new solution.  Now VS hangs when trying to open the C dll project in the new solution.

Mike

Comment: have you tried Devenv /ResetSettings SettingsFile ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried Devenv /ResetSettings.  I've also deleted all of the .suo files.  
To clarify, In Solution Explorer I can click the arrow to expand the other two projects in the solution without a problem.  Trying to expand the third project causes the hang.

Comment: Repairing VS also did not help.  I also replaced the solution with a backup copy of the entire solution and still have the same problem.  I can search for C project file contents and open individual files that way, but I cannot open the project in solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by removing the ClearCase integration from VS.  I am moving to a free version control system shortly anyway, so this won't be a major problem.

Mike